# Creating new Custom Object Record; unable to select from 2x Record Types

Tags: custom-object, page-layout, record-type

I haven't encountered this before: I have 2x Record Types (both confirmed Active) on a custom object and both are each assigned to a unique page layout. I double-checked that each page layout-to-Record Type assignment was correcly laid out along with the corresponding Security Profiles (this object has same layout for all user profiles).

When I try to create a new Custom Object record however, there is no 'Select  [Custom Object] Record Type' picklist page, the user is immediately defaulted to the 'pre-Insert' Edit Record page.

This is frustratingly basic, is there something else I am overlooking that would cause me to be unable to first Select the Custom Object Record type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1)Go to the personal settings and select Record type Selection and make sure you have unchecked the objects in the data types column . Please see below image .Also click on that to expand for proper view .

[image]

2)Also another cause can be your profile does not have access to the other record types .Go to Profiles | record type settings | Select the Object | Edit   to fix the same

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response!! The 2nd Option did the trick! Weird, never had to use this before..

Comment: Please mark as answered .

Comment: Right ahead of you there ;-)